# Invalid type conversion in c threads, void* to int

Tags: c, unix, type-conversion, pthreads

First of all i hope you are all safe. I am trying to pass an array which contains the threadIDs of the threads created in C. I know the program is full of errors but I am getting one error that I don't know how to resolve. At the line where i write  threadID[i]=(int*)tid[i]; I get invalid type conversion. What Im trying to do in convert void* to int and I get that error. I am pretty bad at C but I am trying to learn. If I could get any help I would appreciate it

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int x=0;


void* printMsg(void *tid)
{
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    int nthreads;
    //Get the number of threads
    nthreads= sizeof(tid);

    //Copy thread array from main to threadID array
    int *threadID[nthreads];
;
    for(int i=0;i<nthreads;i++)
        threadID[i]=(int*)tid[i];

    if(pthread_equal(id,threadID[x]))
    {
        printf("%d\n",x);
        x++;
    }
    while(1);
}

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int n=0;

    printf("Enter number of threads : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    pthread_t tid[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &printMsg, (void*)tid);
    }

    for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); 
    } 

    sleep(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because the function printMsg can only accept void* arguements i think. The print is for printing a number. Basically the program needs for each thread to print the var x . So if i want to create 10 threads the first thread would have to print 1,the second 2 and so on

Comment: It would be good to put what you want the code to do into the question itself. Also, you can't use `sizeof` on a pointer (i.e. you can, but the result won't be what you expect). C arrays know they're arrays only in their scope; as soon as you pass them into a function, they forget all about size, so you have to remember the size yourself.

Comment: Okay thanks, my bad will do next time. I will do some more digging and update it if i find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is to let the thread know which thread it is at creation time. You can do that by passing the thread ID as an argument. Here's a way you can do that:

```
void *printMsg(void *tnum_p) {
    int tnum = *(int *)tnum_p;
    printf("%d\n", tnum);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;

    printf("Enter number of threads: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    pthread_t tid[n];
    int tnum[n];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tnum[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &printMsg, &(tnum[i]));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One might think that we could just pass `&i` instead of `&(tnum[i])`; this would compile without any error, but then each thread would receive the same address, and it would be up to the luck and timing what each thread finds there (i.e. you'd almost certainly have repeated numbers).

(I also prefer `tid + i` and `tnum + i` instead of `&(tid[i])` and `&(tnum[i])`, but that's just me.)

If you need to send any other information, then make a `struct` to carry everything you need, instead of passing an `int`.